# Unable to enable hot reload for React on docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker so I'm sure I'm missing something.

I'm trying to create a container with a react app. I'm using docker on a Windows 10 machine.

This is my docker file

```
FROM node:latest

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent


COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["npm","run", "start"]
```

and this is my docker compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  sample:
    container_name: prova-react1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

When i start the container if I go on the browser everything is working fine but when i go back to Visual Studio Code and I make a modification to the files and save nothing occurs to the container and even to the website

Comment: Can you install Node locally and use that for day-to-day development, instead of trying to introduce Docker into it?

Comment: (I suspect you're having trouble because the anonymous volume you mount on the `node_modules` directory is empty.  In the Dockerfile you `RUN npm install` before you switch to the `/app` directory, so there's nothing in `/app` in the image.  The anonymous volume declaration tells Docker that `node_modules` contains user data that must not be lost or automatically modified, so when you do make this change you'll need to also make sure you delete the volumes and start over.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried as you say to swap lines but nothing changes